# Flutter integrated stacked and tabbed navigations

Tags: flutter, navigation

Consider following application (it's a schematic preview and it may be a bit tricky to understand!):

[image]

The app contains 3 screens, which is as follows:

- **Screen 1**: a simple screen which has a simple content (like a web page content without any specific link to another page).
- **Screen 2**: a stacked content which you can navigate through widgets with basic Navigator methods such as pop and push.
- **Screen 3**: a tabbed content, such as bottom navigation bar or tab bar, which has two tabs `a` and `b`, which every one of them again has a stacked content.

**Note:** contents with underlined names are defaults, i.e., Screen3,a,i shows when you open app for the first time.

**Problem**

We want to navigate through whole of the application content using named routes. Consider contents named as follows:

```
/
/Screen1
/Screen2/b
/Screen3/a
/Screen3/a/ii
```

So the following navigation scenarios as examples are expected:

```
 1. /Screen1 <=> /Screen2/a
 2. /Screen1/a <=> /Screen3
 3. /Screen1/a <=> /Screen3/b
 4. /Screen1/a <=> /Screen3/a/iii
 5. /Screen2/a <=> /Screen2/c
 6. /Screen2/c <=> /Screen3/b
 7. /Screen3/a/i <=> /Screen3/b/ii
 8. /Screen3/a/i <=> /Screen3/a/iii
```

**Useful Links**

Here are some useful and advance tutorials about navigation on flutter.

[Flutter Case Study: Multiple Navigators with BottomNavigationBar](https://medium.com/coding-with-flutter/flutter-case-study-multiple-navigators-with-bottomnavigationbar-90eb6caa6dbf)

[Nested navigation with a bottom navigation bar using Flutter](https://medium.com/@Mr_Pepe/nested-navigation-with-a-bottom-navigation-bar-using-flutter-d3c5086fbcdc)

[Common bottom navigation bar made easy — Flutter](https://medium.com/swlh/common-bottom-navigation-bar-made-easy-flutter-199c9f683b29)

[Bottom Navigation in Flutter: Mastery Guide](https://edsonbueno.com/2020/01/23/bottom-navigation-in-flutter-mastery-guide/)

[Navigator class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html)

[Learning Flutter’s new navigation and routing system](https://medium.com/flutter/learning-flutters-new-navigation-and-routing-system-7c9068155ade)

**Update**

Partially implemented of above scenario attached below, help me to complete missed routing buttons.

https://dartpad.dev/1616a3d1a4c06ebd32ef8dd7b77d00d9

Comment: What is your question? Don't know how to navigate?

Comment: In general: `We want to navigate through whole of the application content using named routes.`

But if I want to ask finer questions, these are some of them:

1. How we can navigate from the `/Screen3/a/i` to `/Screen3/b/ii` using named routes (not index of tabs), and what about pop behavior?

2. How we can navigate from `/Screen1` to a content on one of tabs? (such as `/Screen3/b/ii` for e.g)

In general, I want an implementation which supports top 8 mentioned navigation scenarios.

Comment: Can't use `Navigator.pushNamed()` ?

Comment: At least we have 4 Navigator on above scenario, call `pushNamed() ` on which one?
- Root Navigator,

- Navigator for Screen 2

- Navigator for `a` tab of Screen 3

- Navigator for `b` tab of Screen 3

- and maybe a custom Navigator for switching between Screen 3 tabs

Comment: a sample source code attached to the question