# Flutter BottomNavigationBar with Navigator and without replacement (loosing state)

Tags: flutter, navigation, flutter-bottomnavigation

How we can change `BottomNavigationBar` page using `Navigator` push method without losing each page state?

extra details: that is useful on nested navigation, when we want to use `Navigator.of` method to access nearest `Navigator` on widget hierarchy. so we can change tabs from inside a tab content.
this situation is also a part of explained scenario on this question [Flutter integrated stacked and tabbed navigations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65277141/flutter-integrated-stacked-and-tabbed-navigations).

Answer (score 0):

Use  **AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin** .
After loading first time page state,there is no need to reload this(mens it's not losing it's old state)

Like this,

```
class ListWidget extends StatefulWidget { @override 
_ListWidgetState createState() => _ListWidgetState();
    
  } 
    
    class _ListWidgetState extends State<ListWidget> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<ListWidget>{ // ** here 
    @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) { return Container(); 
    } 
    @override
     bool get wantKeepAlive => true; 
     }
```